# Jasper Reports:java.sql.SQLException: ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item

Tags: oracle, plsql, jasper-reports

I have requirment same output format have different reports and different tables.So what i implemented Oracle Piplined functions and jasper report >Report Query wrote below

Oracle Stored Procedure

```
FUNCTION VENDOR_TYPE(REPORT_TYPE IN VARCHAR2) RETURN T_VENDOR_TYPE pipelined

C1 sys_refcursor;

out_rec VENDOR_TYPE := VENDOR_TYPE(0, null, null, null);
BEGIN
IF REPORT_TYPE='1' THEN
OPEN C1 FOR SELECT .....;
ELSIF REPORT_TYPE='2' THEN
OPEN C1 FOR SELECT .....;
END IF;
LOOP 
FETCH C1 INTO out_rec.VENDOR,out_rec.VENDOR_ID;
EXIT WHEN C1%NOTFOUND;
PIPE ROW(out_rec);

END LOOP
CLOSE C1;
RETURN;

END VENDOR_TYPE
```

My query is :

```
select * from table(VENDOR_TYPE('1')) - was running fine
```

But I had created two parameters and change the query as

```
select * from table(VENDOR_TYPE($P{report_no}))
```

After I have executed the report it gives me the error as follows "java.sql.SQLException: ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item ". Can you please help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to CAST:

```
select * from table(CAST(VENDOR_TYPE($P{report_no}) AS VENDOR_TYPE))
```

Comment: Thank you its working.Is there any cons side for this implementation.